# How can I read the XML file Node attributes and Child node attributes values?

Tags: c#

How can I read the xml file having contents :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A>
   <B value="1">
     <Hash algo="SHA256" value="905C45B51B970434D7159641D9F6A88DC91E9C35030618A729C8E4BE174711AF" />
   </B>
   <B value="2">
     <Hash algo="SHA256" value="649721FF455E9B100E691A3857696350E14364029C34C9438AB3EA9665C91292" />
   </B>
   <B value="3">
     <Hash algo="SHA256" value="90FC91C4B82BF440FDAFECF3303DCA8FB9F2E9D7EFFAE394D8B74D0C7CD7DA10" />
   </B>
</A>
```

In the above xml file I want to read the values of all `B` tag's "value" attribute values and the tag `Hash` "algorithm" or "value" attributes value.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
        using (var stm = new FileStream(@"xmlFilePath", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stm, settings))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string srcFileHash=null;
                reader.ReadToDescendant("B");
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "B")
                {
                    reader.MoveToAttribute("value");
                    var bValue=reader.Value;   // get the B tag attribute value.

                    //also want to read the <hash value=? and algo=?. but I dnt know how to get these hash tag attributes.
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, and very welcome to SO! What have you tried yourself? There are several different methods to read and parse XML using .NET libraries, as well as third party libraries. If you try looking through the related questions on your lower right, I'm sure there are several answers already available. =)

Comment: There are many examples here that can lehp you: [How to: Parse XML with XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: I see no reason to down vote this question it is legitimate, yes its old and its in every book in the world but we can help this person by providing a legitimate answer.

Comment: The code you are using is very long winded and there are better ways to accomplish this exact task, L.Bs solution, Mine and the version by HatSoft accomplish exactly what you want, The difference is you are using forward only reading and we are not we are using random access, is this important to your solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var result = xDoc.Descendants("B")
    .Select(b => new
    {
        BValue = b.Attribute("value").Value,
        Alg = b.Element("Hash").Attribute("algo").Value,
        AlgValue = b.Element("Hash").Attribute("value").Value,
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(yourxmlfilename);//Load the document

foreach (XElement b in doc.Elements("B"))//Iterate all elements B
{
    var xAttribute = b.Attribute("value");//get attribute called value
    if (xAttribute != null)
    {
        string v = xAttribute.Value;//now you have the B value
    }

    foreach (XElement h in b.Elements("Hash"))//Iterate all elements Hash
    {
        var xAttributev = h.Attribute("value");//get attribute called value
        if (xAttributev != null)
        {
               string hashValue = xAttribute.Value;//now you have the Hash value
        }

        var xAttributeh = h.Attribute("algo");//get attribute called algo
        if (xAttributeh != null)
        {
           string algorithm = xAttributeh.Value;//now you have the Hash algorithm
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain the -1 for i cannot see whats the issue with my answer

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but odds are good that the downvote is because it's a code-only answer. We prefer that people use text to at least explain the issue, rather than just handing out code.

Comment: @NicolBolas agree with you i will update my answer with explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but here is some quick code to do what you want.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"file.xml");
if (xdoc.Root != null)
{
    var bs = xdoc.Root.Descendants("B");

    foreach (var bNode in bs)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("B Value: " + bNode.FirstAttribute.Value);
        var hash = bNode.XPathSelectElement("Hash");
        Console.Out.WriteLine("algo is : " + hash.FirstAttribute.Value);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("value is : " + hash.FirstAttribute.NextAttribute.Value);
    } 
}
```

I would suggest brushing up on XDocument and XmlDocument (both are still relevant depending on how old your code is :)